# How to calculate 'real-world' geometric height from ERA reanalysis data

Tags: reanalysis, era, coordinate-system

This seems like a really simple question, but I have been struggling for a couple of days to find an answer online or in the ERA documentation.

I am using ERA5 and ERA Interim reanalyses to get atmospheric profiles for a model I am running.
However, the model requires values to be given at fixed values of altitude (above sea level) (it is a rectangular grid 60x60x60 km).

The data I get from ERA (downloaded using the python script API they suggest) gives me data on either pressure level or model level. I can get geopotential as a variable, but there is no option for 'real-world' height.

So my question is how do I calculate the 'real' altitude of each level?

I initially tried dividing geopotential by 9.81, but I'm not sure that's quite right, as geopotential is an integral of g.
Alternatively should I be using the values in the tables [here](https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/documentation-and-support/60-model-levels), and if so why are they not provided as an option of a variable or coordinate when downloading the data?

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question with a simple answer and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question right:
[CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-6630002.12.10) can interpolate from model level to height level with the operator

> ml2hl infile.nc outfile.nc

additionally, for the lower atmospheric levels, you can add an extrapolation option.
BUT I don't recommend it since its extrapolation performance is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions.

1. Use [MetPy](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.geopotential_to_height.html?highlight=height#metpy.calc.geopotential_to_height) to calculate the height from the geopotential height.
2. Use the [hypsometric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypsometric_equation), averaging the temperature below the level.